# javascript eval how to

Tags: javascript

var obj = {x : 2};
    eval.call(obj, 'x');  // ReferenceError: x is not defined
How to change last line to get value by variable name?

**Clarification**
'x' - any expression in some obj context, possibly not a obj parameter

**Original problem**

```
/**
 * Guards 'this' when delegating method as a callback to others. Arguments aren't known beforehand and will be provided by consumer.
 */
delegate = function(context, func) {
    return function() {
        var args = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

reference = function (context, 'expression to evaluete to get reference value') {
    ... TODO
};
```

'delegate' - delegates function call, how to 'delegate a reference' with possibility to 'dereference' in different context?

**Updates**
here is 2 possibilities to use eval:
1. eval.call(null, 'evaluate expression in global context');
2. eval('evaluate expression in context where eval function was called')
3. how to eval in some predefined 'context' ?

I want to mimic C++ reference when you can put it in any context and 'dereference' to value (but when in moment you dereference it value could be changed and you should get new value). Like in javascript you put object as function argument and anytime you get obj.someproperty you'll get newest someproperty value (if it was changed). But this will not work when you will try to pass a primitive or what if whole object will be changed by some other. How to 'pass a reference' to 'whole object' to some other context?

Got clear understanding what I want :)
[javascript how to create reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823870/javascript-how-to-create-reference)

What I was looking for:

```
createReference = function(context, prop) {
    return function() {
        return context[prop];
    };
};

Provider = function() {
};
Provider.prototype.x = 5;
Provider.prototype.getXRef = function() {
    return createReference(this, 'x');
};
Provider.prototype.incrementX = function() {
    this.x = this.x + 1;
};

var provider = new Provider();
var refX = provider.getXRef();
provider.incrementX();
alert(refX());
```

Tanks Brianpeiris!

Comment: What is the problem with `obj.x` ? Or `obj['x']` ?

Comment: I think eval.call() only works if you call a function, not a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually trying to achieve, but the way you are going about it is horrible. Take a step back and explain the problem you are trying to solve with this syntax (instead of trying figure out how to get the syntax to work).

Comment: I assume he has an object literal and names of properties as strings. So he has to retrieve values from the object using the strings.

Comment: @Click: That's actually how you use `call` (the first parameter is the `this` object to use during the call). But `call` doesn't apply to `eval`, `eval` isn't really a function, it's a language construct, and it does things that real functions can't do. It just looks and feels very much like a function.

Comment: @Mykhaylo: Again, to David's point, can you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve? Because there **will** be a better way than `eval`.

Comment: What is an *expression in some obj context*? Please provide a better example. Currently it seems that `obj['x']` should do it.

Comment: Here’s something to read: *[Global eval. What are the options?](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)*

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. So `'expression to evaluete to get reference value'` will result in a property name of context? Btw. you don't have to create a new array, you can pass `arguments` directly: `func.apply(context, arguments);`. Maybe you should also have a look at the implementation (or something close) of `bind` in ECMAScript 5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Mykhaylo: Your "Original problem" code doesn't explain what you want to do. The `delegate` function seems completely unrelated, as it never calls `reference`. The `reference` function doesn't give enough information to explain why the several answers below aren't what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mykhaylo You're question is useful but you didn't state it very clearly to begin with. In future, please try to put some effort in to asking a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it, no need for eval:

```
var obj = {x: 2};
var value = obj['x'];
```

Comment: @NeXXeuS What if you only had a string? In other words, if you only had `var propertyName = 'x', obj = {x: 2};`, you can't do `obj.propertyName` (obviously).

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: I *may* understand now, or at least I have two guesses. See **Update 1** and **Update 2** below.

---

**Original answer**:

You almost never need `eval`. But just so you know, you're not alone, there are a lot of people who think you have to use `eval` for this. It's actually a *lot* easier than that.

If you want to access a property in an object, you can use either dotted notation (`obj.x`) or bracketed notation (`obj['x']`). Note the quotes in the latter: All property names are strings, and the bracket notation lets us use actual strings when looking up properties. So given this object:

```
var obj = {foo: 42};
```

**all** of these put 42 in `x`:

```
x = obj.foo;
x = obj['foo'];
x = obj['f' + 'o' + 'o'];
y = 'foo'; x = obj[y];   // Using the "foo" string from variable `y`
x = obj[getTheAnswer()]; // Using the return value of a function (`getTheAnswer` returns "foo")
```

As you can see, you can use any expression to come up with the name of the property (as a string), and then use that property name string in the brackets.

---

**Update 1**: In your `reference` function, if you literally want to *accept a string* containing an expression you know nothing about, evaluate the string, and use the result to look up a property on the object, here's how you do that — I want to be clear that I would strongly recommend solving this problem a different way, but without knowing more about the actual problem, I couldn't say how. So here it is:

```
var reference = function(context, expressionString) {
    return context[eval(expressionString)];
};
```

So for example:

```
var obj = {p5: 42};
alert(reference(obj, "'p' + (4 + 1)")); // alerts 42
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/odusu4)

Apologies if I've guessed wrong.

---

**Update 2**:

From the fact that you're giving `delegate` and `reference` together, and the comment *"... how to 'delegate a reference' with possibility to 'dereference' in different context?..."* it sounds like you're trying to find a way to find out what the *original* function was, if you only have the delegate. E.g.:

```
function foo() { ... }
var fooDelegate = delegate(someObject, foo);
var original = reference(someObject, fooDelegate);
alert(original === foo); // alerts true
```

If *that's* what you're trying to do, you can't do it without setting something up in `delegate` that you later look for in `reference`. Fortunately, that's easy:

```
// Create a function that, when called, will always call the given
// function with the given context, passing along the call arguments.
delegate = function(context, func) {
    var newFunc = function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
    newFunc.__delegate__original = func;
    return newFunc;
};

// If given a function created by `delegate`, returns the original
// underlying function. If the given function is not from `delegate`,
// returns `func` unchanged.
reference = function(func) {
    return func.__delegate__original || func;
};
```

Note that you don't need the `context` parameter on `reference.`

And again, apologies if I'm guessing wrong.

---

**Off-topic**: Re your `delegate` function, you'll be glad to know that you *don't* have to copy the `arguments` before you pass them into `apply`. (You *do* probably want to return the return value of the target function, though.) This works fine cross-implementation:

```
delegate = function(context, func) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
};
```

...because `apply` is carefully defined in the specification to allow any array-like object, it doesn't require an actual `Array` instance. See Section 15.3.4.3 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for details.

Comment: +1 for `42`, but should `getTheAnswer()` not return `42`? (kidding ;))

Comment: it appeared not working in IE for me due to arguments is not an array but object

Comment: @Mykhaylo: It must have been something else, it works fine on IE, all the way back to IE6: http://jsbin.com/usexo3

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Nicely done, I think you actually understood what he was getting at :)

Comment: @Mykhaylo: *"thanks for helping"* A pleasure, no worries. I have to take off, but I've added a second guess to the answer. Regardless, good luck with things.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @brianpeiris's answer, you can decide what parameter you want to read from the object dynamically, at runtime.  For example:

```
var obj = {x: 2);
var field = 'x'; // or do some other operation to figure out the field you want
var value = obj[field];
if (value) {
  // the field exists and has a true value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you absolutely have to use eval:


`var obj = {x : 2};
var myVar = eval(obj.x);
alert(myVar);`

Overkill, I know.

Comment: I think this is not helpful. If he can call `obj.x` then there is no need for `eval`.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bad answer and I should feel bad.