# JavaScript passing variable as value and not as reference

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

My problem is simple I think, but I couldn't find a simple solution to it. Here is the example:

```
var obj1 = {
    m1:"a",
    m2:"b" 
};

var obj2 = {
    m:obj1
};


obj2.m.m1 = "c";


document.write(obj2.m.m1+"<br>"); //output: c

document.write(obj1.m1+"<br>"); // output: c ( I wanted to be a)
```

So.. what do I need to do to return "a" from obj1.m1 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript how to create reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823870/javascript-how-to-create-reference)

Comment: @David Dorwad  actually I'm looking for the opposite thing. How to pass objects as value and not as refference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `obj2.m` to a clone of `obj1`, not `obj1` itself. For instance:

```
function clone(obj) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return result;
}

var obj2 = {
    m: clone(obj1)
};

obj2.m.m1 = "c";  // does not affect obj1.m1
```

Comment: Note that I am specifically /not/ attaching the `clone` function to `Object.prototype` because that is, in general, a Very Bad Idea. Also, this is a very simple implementation of a clone function; for a more complete one, check out the implementation of jQuery.extend.

Answer (score 4):

This may be of use:

http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165

Comment: Note that augmenting the `Object` object is a very bad idea, because it breaks use of `for in` unless you are scrupulous about filtering out prototypes. See: http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/

Answer (score 1):

`obj1` and `obj2.m` point to the *same* object. You cannot have `obj1.m1 != obj2.m.m1`

What you can do is assign a copy of `obj1` to `obj2.m`. See the link Will posted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clone it first.

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};

var obj1={    m1:"a",    m2:"b" };
var obj2={    m: {}};
obj2.m = obj1.clone();
obj2.m.m1="c";
document.write(obj2.m.m1+"<br>"); 
document.write(obj1.m1+"<br>");
```